# Limit and Integration are interchangeable

Tags: real-analysis, limits, sequence-of-function

> Let $f_n:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f_n(x)=\frac{n+x^3\cos x}{ne^x+x^5\sin x}$,  $n\geq 1$. Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1f_n(x)dx$.

*Approach*: Here I found the limit function $f(x)=e^{-x}$. So, if I can interchange the limit and integration, then easy to find solution. But we can do that only when the convergence to $f$ is uniform. I am not getting the idea to show this convergence is uniform.

Answer (score 6):

$ 0\leq f_n(x) \leq \frac {n+1} {ne^{x}-1}$. Now $\frac {n+1} {ne^{x}-1} \leq \frac {n+1} {n-1} \leq 2$ for $n \geq 3$ for all $x$ so we can apply DC T to interchange the limit and the integral.

Alternatively you can verify that $|f_n(x)-e^{-x}| \leq \frac {1+e} {n-1}$ which gives uniform convergence.

Comment: Please explain me the inequality. How did you get this inequality?

Comment: @SumitSah If you are comfortable with using uniform convergence you can use the second method I have suggested. The inequality in this method uses some simple algebra and the inequalities $|\sin \,x | \leq 1, |\cos \,x | \leq 1$ and $e^{x} \leq e$ for $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: yes. I'm comfortable with uniform convergence. But initially you solved using Dominated Convergence Theorem. I also want to apply this. How did you find the inequality in first case?

Comment: @SumitSah First note that the numerator is $\leq n+1$. Next note that the denominator is $\geq ne^{x}-1 \geq n-1$. Here you use the in equality $|a+b| \geq |a|-|b|$.  I hope you can now arrive at the inequality.

Comment: Yes, Sure. Thank You.

Answer (score 6):

Note that for $x\in [0,1]$, $0\leq \sin(x)\leq 1$, $0\leq \cos(x)\leq 1$, $0<e^{-x}\leq 1$ and
$$|f_n(x)-e^{-x}|=e^{-x}\left|\frac{1+\frac{x^3\cos x}{n}}{1+\frac{x^5e^{-x}\sin x}{n}}-1\right|=\frac{e^{-x}}{n}\frac{|x^3\cos x-x^5e^{-x}\sin x|}{1+\frac{x^5e^{-x}\sin x}{n}}\\
\leq \frac{1}{n}\frac{|x^3\cos x|+|x^5e^{-x}\sin x|}{1}\leq \frac{2}{n}.$$
and therefore $f_n\to e^{-x}$ uniformly over $[0,1]$.